# how to skip unique constraint?

Tags: entity-framework-5, unique-constraint

I have tried to insert many records into a table, and this table has a unique constraint, so when if one user try to add a new record with the same unique value, I get the dbUpdateException.

But I would like to know how to skipt this error and try to add the remaining records that the first user are trying to add to the table.

How can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to catch the DbUpdateException, and use its Entries property to remove the duplicate entities from the context.

You could then retry the save - rinse and repeat - and eventually all the non-duplicate entities will be saved.

E.g.

```
var duplicates = new List<MyEntity>();
...
catch(DbUpdateException ex)
{
   ex.Entries.Each(e => DbContext.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Detached;
   duplicates.Add(ex.Entries);
   ReTrySave(); // do whatever you need todo to re-enter your saving code
}
...
// Report to user the duplicate entities
ReportToUser(duplicates);
```

NOTE - treat as pseudo code as I haven't attempted to compile this snippet.

Comment: Thanks. But why this is a dirty solution? Because I was thinking to load from database the duplicate register to return to the user with the ID and information that exists in the database.

Comment: Didn't really mean its bad code - just a little hacky. If it gets the job done I'd have no problem using it. I think my preferred approach would be to check for duplicates before saving and bulk remove them from the context before doing the save. However, as long as you aren't importing a large number of entities all in one go there probably isn't a lot to chose between the two approaches.

Comment: Just to clarify - pre-removal of duplicates would be more work to implement and potentially not worth it for small updates. Hence why I didn't mention it in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks. If i check duplicates and try to save, it's possible that other user add the record before my save changes, so do it before save perhaps not ensure that I can add the record.

Comment: Good point - pre-removal would definitely mean implementing concurrency control. I'm starting to like this approach more and more for its simplicity now ;)